# Urgently choosing SDD - need advice!

Tags: hard-disk

I need to urgently choose an external hard drive. I need IT to run windows 10 on my iMac, since virtual machines shows too low performance in my case. I think I need an SSD, since its data transfer rate faster than the HDD.

I know that if SSD fails - it fails entirely, but I will not store important data on it (I need it for working with Hololens emulator and several other programs). And I hope with careful treatment, he will live longer

So, I'm looking for:
**SSD

500GB or more

$50-150 max**

Here is a model I have found - [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B016JREG84/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016JREG84)
**What do you think about it? Would you recommend different one?**

I need an answer urgently, and I would be very grateful for your help!
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB. More details to follow in an actual answer.

Comment: Forensically there ARE ways of recovering data from an SSD.  Also, as it stands now, there is no way, short of physical destruction of the media to sanitize digital media, as there is with magnetic media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't judge on the given SSD model, I can issue a recommendation for another one.

The [**Samsung 850 EVO 500GB SSD**.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OBRE5UE)

Here's why it's a good SSD:

- **Price.** It's 130USD on Amazon right now and thus just as expensive as the SSD you linked.
- **Speed.** [The 850 Evo will go to 400MB/s no problem.](http://ssd.userbenchmark.com/Samsung-850-Evo-500GB/Rating/3477) Anything beyond that will depend on your system but probably won't make noticeable differences in practice.
- **Durability / Warranty.** [Samsung gives you a **5-year / 150TBW warranty** on this SSD](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/M2M/html/support/warranty.html), meaning Samsung guarantees that your SSD will still work perfectly fine if you use it for less than 5 years and write less than 150TB (300 complete writes over the drive or 84GB / day) during that time-span. Chances are this SSD won't fail you even if you go beyond the 150TBW limit. In fact, even the less-durable predecessor with half the storage (for which Samsung only gives you three years of warranty) survived [300TBW without major issues.](https://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead) It is thus expected that you can go at least up to 500 - 1000TBW without loosing the 850 EVO. If you want even more you need to put down the additional 90USD for a 850 PRO  which should survive a few PB worth of writes.
- **Brand.** Samsung flash storage has a very good reputation.
- **Software.** [Samsung provides software](http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools.html) for all its SSDs to optimize the system perfomance (stuff like enabling AHCI). The software also tells you how much data has already been written on your SSD.

As a non-exhaustive personal opinion: I have used this very SSD for more than 1 year now